# \xc9 accents when exporting a data frame to csv

Tags: pandas

Pandas' `to_csv()` method produces an error when strings in my data frame contain `\xc9` accents. Any idea how I can quickly solve this?

Thanks

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call
>   last) /Users/slegroux1/Projects/FeaturEmo/en_features.py in ()
>       360                 print "----- No plot. Corresponding features are missing."
>       361 if **name** == '**main**':
>   --> 362         main()
>
> /Users/slegroux1/Projects/FeaturEmo/en_features.py in main()
>        40         if output:
>        41                 embed()
>   ---> 42                 dict2frame(features).to_csv(output)
>        43         if plot and not(directory or my_csv_list):
>        44                 plot_features(features)
>
> /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc
>   in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, cols, header,
>   index, index_label, mode, nanRep, encoding, quoting, line_terminator,
>   chunksize, tupleize_cols, **kwds)    1408
>   chunksize=chunksize,engine=kwds.get("engine"),    1409
>   tupleize_cols=tupleize_cols)
>   -> 1410         formatter.save()    1411    1412     def to_excel(self, excel_writer, sheet_name='sheet1', na_rep='',
>
> /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.pyc
>   in save(self)
>       970
>       971             else:
>   --> 972                 self._save()
>       973
>       974
>
> /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.pyc
>   in _save(self)    1076                 break    1077
>   -> 1078             self._save_chunk(start_i, end_i)    1079    1080     def _save_chunk(self, start_i, end_i):
>
> /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.pyc
>   in _save_chunk(self, start_i, end_i)    1094         ix =
>   data_index.to_native_types(slicer=slicer, na_rep=self.na_rep,
>   float_format=self.float_format)    1095
>   -> 1096         lib.write_csv_rows(self.data, ix, self.nlevels, self.cols, self.writer)    1097    1098 # from collections import
>   namedtuple
>
> /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/lib.so
>   in pandas.lib.write_csv_rows (pandas/lib.c:13871)()
>
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc9' in
>   position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify an encoding using the `encoding` argument to `to_csv`. For example, `df.to_csv(filename, encoding='utf-8')`.